# can't stringify json data, single output instead of multiple

Tags: jquery, json, stringify

I got a simple question, I can't make the code to output only one result instead of multiple, i want to get only one first result, but it makes multiple because of `each`

looked up for stringify but couldn't manage to make it work properly

```
$('#form').submit(function(){
    var nick=$('#username').val();
    if(nick.length > 0){ 
        var url='http://api.worldoftanks.ru/2.0/account/list/?application_id=171745d21f7f98fd8878771da1000a31&search='+nick;
        $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
            $('#result').html('');
            $.each(json.data, function(index, data) {
                var id=data.id;
                $('#result').append('<p> ID: ' + id+ '</p>');
            });
        });
    }else{ 
        alert('enter username');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of `each` you can get first id using

```
json.data[0].id
```

Comment: do a console.log(json) and post here in the question

Comment: Object {status: "ok", count: 3, data: Array[3]} , updated code

Answer (score 1):

You could also include "return;" after
appending the json data so that loop will return after the first loop, otherwise it's better to get data using json index.